# Minimal presentation of a tensor product of modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Let $(R,m)$ be a local commutative noetherian ring. Suppose I have two modules $M$ and $N$ over $R$ given in terms of minimal presentations
$$
M = \operatorname{coker}A,
$$
and 
$$
N = \operatorname{coker}B,
$$
where $A$ and $B$ are some matrices with entries in the maximal ideal $m$ (in $m$ because of the minimality condition).

I have two questions:

1. How to find minimal presentation of $M \otimes N$?
2. What is $\operatorname{coker} A \otimes B$?

Comment: For question 1, I was tensoring resolutions, but even in the cases with vanishing Tor_1, the first two steps are much larger than they supposed to be for a minimal presentations. So, I need to use row/column operations in each case individually to produce a minimal presentation. I was hoping that there is something more efficient than this. I asked question 2 out of curiosity, doesn't look to be immediately related to the first question.

Comment: Let $R = k[[x,y]]$, $A=(x,y)$, $B=(x)$, then $A \otimes B \cong (x^2,xy)$ and cokernel of this tensor product of matrices is not isomorphic to tensor product of cokernels, which is $k$.

Comment: Even simpler: $R=k[[x]]$, $A=B=(x)$, then $A \otimes B \cong (x^2)$, cokernel of this matrix is $k[[x]]/(x^2)$, but tensor product of cokernels is still $k$.

Comment: Did you get any updates on this?

Comment: No, no updates.